# What package in NuGet do I need to Install to create charts in OxyPlot?

Tags: xamarin, nuget, xamarin.forms, nuget-package, oxyplot

I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms (Portable) Application where I want to create a Chart. Specifically, using OxyPlot.

But I have a problem,  **OxyPlot** doesn't appear whenever I search it in my Nuget Packages for Solution. Only "oxyplot-extensions", "Eto.OxyPlot.wpf", and "Eto.OxyPlot" appear.

What package do I actually need to create charts using OxyPlot? Is there a specific package I need to Install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this NuGet package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms/). It seems to be only in prerelease. So make sure that when you try to install it you check the box 'include prerelease' (in Visual Studio).

[image: Include prerelease checkbox]

Comment: @GeralVersluis I've found the OxyPlot package Sir. Is it the only package I need to install to create a chart in Xamarin.Forms? Or there's another?

Comment: If there are any dependencies it should install them automatically.

Comment: Sir please take a look at this (http://prntscr.com/bu9a87) The description in the package states that the package is obsolete. What do I need to do?

Comment: Don't really know about that. Maybe check out the [documentation](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms.html) on the Xamarin Forms version.

Comment: I don't know why is that happening. :(